# fprintf have strange effect on timestamp counter

Tags: c, performance, readfile

I have two counters:

```
#define number_of_ccr 1024
unsigned int lpBuffer[number_of_ccr] = {0};
unsigned long nNumberOfBytesToRead =     number_of_ccr*4;
unsigned long lpNumberOfBytesRead;  
unsigned int counter = 0;
unsigned int error = 0;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&fullCounter); // first counter

for(;;) {

  QueryPerformanceCounter(&startCounter); //     second counter 
  error = ReadFile(
    hSerial,
    lpBuffer,
    nNumberOfBytesToRead,
    &lpNumberOfBytesRead,
    NULL
    );

  if(!strcmp(lpBuffer, "end")) {
  CloseHandle(FileHandle);
  //char *copyString = "copy";
  //WriteFile(hSerial, copyString , strlen(copyString), &bytes_written, NULL);
  fprintf(stderr, "end flag was received\n");
  break;
  }
  else if(lpNumberOfBytesRead == nNumberOfBytesToRead) {

  // NOTE(): succeed
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&endCounter);
  time += Win32GetSecondsElapsed(startCounter, endCounter); //second counter

  DWORD BytesWritten;
  // write data to file
  WriteFile(FileHandle, lpBuffer, lpNumberOfBytesRead, &BytesWritten, 0);
    if(!(lpBuffer[0] % 1024)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "bytes %d \r", lpBuffer[0]);// <--- THIS LINE
    }
  }
  else if(lpNumberOfBytesRead < nNumberOfBytesToRead) {
    fprintf(stderr, "bytes %d \n", lpNumberOfBytesRead); 
  }

}// for(;;) 
QueryPerformanceCounter(&fullCounterEnd);
fullTime =   Win32GetSecondsElapsed(fullCounter, fullCounterEnd);           

char DebugBuffer[256];
fprintf(stderr, "time: %f \n", time);
fprintf(stderr, "full time: %f \n", fullTime);
```

if I will comment `fprintf(stderr, "bytes %d \r", lpBuffer[0]);// <--- THIS LINE` second counter will  be approx same time as fist counter (fullCounter). When this line is uncommented second  timer is almost twice less than first counter. Presence of this line is the only difference.

Overall: 
If `fprintf`is NOT COMMENTED my counter show BETTER `readfile` performance --> second counter has LESSER time

If `fprintf` COMMENTED I have WORSE performance --> second counter has MORE time on it

compiler flags: cl -Z7 -nologo -Fmsource.map ../code/source.c

cmder log:

```
C:\Documents\work\region\testProject\build (master -> origin)
λ source.exe
Opening serial port...OK
Sending bytes...9 bytes written
end flag was received
time: 0.193245
full time: 0.206170
Closing serial port...OK

C:\Documents\work\region\testProject\build (master -> origin)
λ source.exe
Opening serial port...OK
Sending bytes...9 bytes written
end flag was received
time: 0.115640
full time: 0.204010
Closing serial port...OK
```

My question is, why is this happen? What kind of effect it have on my program?

Comment: @Gerhardh, I'm really sorry, I post this question using smartphone application. I'm doing already  indentation adjustments

Comment: Unfortunately you are not providing an [mcve] (serial config, number of bytes to read) and you are not telling us how the writing to the serial is done. By the way: your code is broken. It expects a) "end" to be at the start of the buffer and b) "end" to be read completely during one `ReadFile`. Both assumptions might not be true.

Comment: What is the type of lpBuffer (I assumed `char` but see `lpBuffer[0] % 1024`)? How many bytes do you read in total (how many chunks, how many bytes per chunk)?

Comment: @WernerHenze, I have my serial input from MCU(cortex m7 h743zi). And I literally can't provide verifiable example because it will require a piece of external hardware. About "end" it's a little hack and I have control over when this specific dummy packet (with first buffer entry contain 0x646E65 - "end" ) will be send

Comment: @WernerHenze it's unsigned int. I'm reading 1024*4 bytes in chunk 60 chunks (61440*4 bytes overall)

Comment: While `fprintf` is executing, the serial keeps accumulating incoming data. The next time you try to read, the data is readily available. Without `fprintf`, the program has to wait for it inside `ReadFile`. Therefore a discrepancy.

Comment: @user58697 sounds reasonable, thanks! Would you mind making an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `fprintf` is executing, the serial keeps accumulating incoming data. The next time you try to read, the data is readily available. Without `fprintf`, the program has to wait for it inside `ReadFile`. Therefore a discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

printing on the console can be an intense time consuming operation, many times reaching even thousands of clock cycles.
Have a look at this [link](https://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/tag/printf/) where it is explained the time consumed by using printf. I know in your case you are using fprintf, but your destination file is still the console output, requiring so the whole process of interrupt, context switch, printing on console, etc.
I cite this piece of code from the link:

```
int main( void )
{
    int i = 89;

    printf("hello, world %d\n", i);
}
```

This might seems as a small and fast code, but it requires 6371 cycles on a RISC CPU. So imagine having a 1MHz RISC CPU, this would require more than 6 ms to execute.

Now imagine that if you are running your code on a computer with OS there are even more delay introduced by the switching between processes and threads and interrupts routines.

Comment: But in my case time consumed by readfile function and some minuscule lines of code is getting less, not more. Did I understand you right?

Comment: from your question I state that commenting the fprintf invocation your program is faster. So I imagine that you run anyway the ReadFile method, otherwise your buffer would not be filled.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I express this poorly, when I do printing, `readfile` take less time

Comment: In the given output the overall time is the same with or without printing.

Comment: @WernerHenze I've tried running this code with printing and without using the clock() function to count ticks. I got a result of 95 ticks with printing and a single tick without, so I don't understand how you can get the same time...

Comment: @user9403409 Ok so I didn't understand correctly the initial question. Now that it has been edited it is clearer for me.

Comment: @WernerHenze time that readfile function takes was measured with `starrCounter` and `endCounter`. This counter was expressed as plain "time" not full time